# access barcode scanners output?

Tags: barcode, qr-code, warehouse

I need to use a wireless barcode scanner to scan a barcode and send the data to the application located on a computer and then the computer processes the data given.

but I don't know how should I make my application listening for the barcode info over WIFI,

how can I do that?

and can barcode scanners send data to a web form automatically? (GET)

and another question , do you think QR-codes are suitable for warehouse management?
thank you

Comment: perhaps i can provide a possible scenario + solution:   assuming the scanner is an Android phone.   So u download one of the many possible QR code reader for Android:   eg, https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en and then sent this via browser and WIFI to another internal server on the WIFI network.   No problem.   
For warehouse management I don't know anything:   http://www.wavelogix.net/warehouse_management.php for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really, really depends on the interface that your scanner provides. As long as you are both connected to the same WiFi network, you can probably just access it via its IP. But how you specifically connect will vary between scanners.

About the web form, I doubt it will support that. But again it depends on the scanner. You'll most likely have some method of it PUSHing data.

I think the question you need to ask about the tracking isn't specifically about QR Codes, but rather whether a 2D bar code is what you need at all. Warehouses are increasingly moving over to RFID for internal tracking, and with RFID labels dropping in price they're viable too. If you want to stick to an ink-based approach, what advantage will a 2D bar code have over a basic 1D one in your scenario?

The latter is much easier to deal with, yet does somewhat rely on orientation unless you have a multi-directional scanner. In that case, you'll probably find it more reliable; it's going to be using a laser as opposed to having to essentially photograph and decode the 2D code.